# Global pointer and dangling pointer

Tags: c, pointers, dangling-pointer

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int *p;
void f()
{
    int a=5;
    p=&a;
    printf("%d ",*p);
}
void main()
{
    f();
    printf("%d",*p);
}
```

Why the O/P is 5 5?
After the function call is over then the local variable a is removed. So p should be pointing to invalid object

Comment: Because undefined behaviour is not guaranteed to go wrong. What happens is undefined, but it happened to work. If you insert another function call between `f();` and `printf("%d",*p);` you might get a different result.

Comment: After returning from a function, C does not waste time initializing local data; it just leaves as it is. But keep in mind that; when the function is in scope, its data (the memory space that belongs to the function) is protected against being overwritten. When the code pointer hits the `return` line of the function however, all the memory space is left as it is but very susceptible to be overwritten (not protected any more). After returning from function, `main` may or may not print `5`, depending on the local memory being overwritten or not.

Comment: @aditi19 If you do not understand a certain phrase of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60393887/12139179), please let me know to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

If it is undefined behavior then it is also allowed to (occasionally) give the output of 5. But don't be surprised if the next morning it gives out 6.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the Output 5 5?

It is because of something called "[Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/12139179)". Undefined Behavior do not have to always provide the wrong result.

> After the function call is over then the local variable `a` is removed. So `p` should be pointing to invalid object.

Exactly, it is pointing to an *invalid* object or better said to no object at all - the `int` object of `a` allocated inside of the function `f()` is already deallocated at the point of executing `printf("%d",*p);` in `main()`.

To dereference a pointer with an stored address to an no longer existant object is [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/12139179).

It could print out anything. That it print out `5` is just a lucky shot, but never reliable. Even when executing the exact same file a second time, you already could get a different result.